# flipboard in Android

Tags: android, flipboard

I want to use clipboard effect on android. I've seen some source codes about it. But all of them are simply flipping over some static pictures(Bitmap).I want to flip a view, and the view changes dynamically. How can I flip over this sort of view? I've tried to take a snapshot of the view, then use the snapshot to flip. But it seems that I can only snapshot a view after it presents on screen. How can I get the Bitmap of a view without present the view on screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to draw your view hierarchy onto a bitmap and then use that for the animation.  [This blog post](http://www.brighthub.com/mobile/google-android/articles/30676.aspx) contains a few simple instructions.  Basically it boils down to:

```
Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(screenWidth, screenHeight,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(auxBitmap);
myview.draw(canvas);
```

Where myview is the view hierarchy you wish to draw (either created in code or an inflated layout) and returnedBitmap is your bitmap with the view on it.